# Error "Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found"

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, fedora

I'm using Fedora 29.
I'm try to run `mariadb.service` with command:
 `systemctl start mariadb`,
 and give error:
 `Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.`

Also, I tried next commands:
`systemctl status mariadb`
`Unit mariadb.service could not be found.`

`systemctl start mariadb.service`
`Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.`

`systemctl start mysql`
`Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.`

`systemctl enable mariadb`
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file mariadb.service does not exist.`

`systemctl daemon-reload`
`<nothing to output>`

I trying this with `sudo` and without. The result is same.

`mariadb-server` is installed:
`dnf install mariadb-server
Package mysql-community-server-8.0.15-1.fc29.x86_64 already installed.`

Just starting to use Linux, I can not understand what's the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You have MySQL 8 installed which is why your installation of MariaDB failed: the two conflict and you must pick which one you want.

If you want to install MariaDB, you first have to uninstall MySQL 8 first:

```
dnf remove mysql-community-server
dnf install mariadb-server
```

Historically, both MySQL and MariaDB used to use `mysql` as the service name. The MySQL 8 package uses only the `mysql` service name whereas MariaDB has both `mariadb` and `mysql` services, the latter being an alias to the `mariadb` one.

MariaDB added its own service name quite early on in the 10 series of releases and has added aliases for other commands as well. For example, the `mariadb` command is the same program as the `mysql` command in MariaDB 10.5.

Comment: I had a similar issue upgrading from Debian 10 to 11 (list what you have with `dpkg -l | grep -iE "(maria|mysql)" | grep -i server`). `mariadb-server...` removed, seems to be "replaced" for `mariadb-server-core-10.3`. Fixed with `apt install mariadb-server`

Comment: I confirm the comment from @Pablo, though slightly modified. In Debian 10, after installing mariadb-server-10.3 and associated packages (galera-3, mariadb-server-core-10.3 and socat), the command `systemctl start mysql` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It was quite confusing to me too. I followed several instructions found online but it seems that even talking about the same version 5.5 there are quite a few different ways to start the service after installation. I finally accidentally tried mysql and it worked.

when seeing this after a successful installation:

> Installed:   MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:5.5.67-1.el7.centos
>
> Dependency Installed:   MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:5.5.67-1.el7.centos
>
> Complete!

and I tried:

> $ sudo systemctl start mariadb
>
> Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit not found.

and I tried:

> $ sudo systemctl start mysql

there was a silence.
and I tried:

> $ sudo systemctl status mysql

It said it's active(running).

Answer (score -1):

you can use `rpm -ql mysql-community-server-8.0.15-1` in order to find where the package is installed. then you can find executables from this path and try to run it